# Can I reference a class from a method within an inner class, and if so, how?

Tags: java, inner-classes

ALERT:  New to Java

I have tried the following to make the outer class the parent to the filechooser, but it refers to OuterClass.AddBrowseActionListener instead of OuterClass:

```
public class OuterClass extends JFrame{

...

    class AddBrowseActionListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            File infile = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(infile.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I know about anonymous classes so you don't have to show me about that unless that is the only way to solve the problem.

Also, using reflection isn't really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, `this` is no more than a private member of the containing object, therefore you can use the class to find the field:

```
int returnValue = filechooser.showOpenDialog(OuterClass.this);
```

This is known as the ["Qualified `this`"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
int returnValue = filechooser.showOpenDialog(OuterClass.this);
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works?